# Class design for Token, TokenType and regex constants

Tags: java, class-design, class

For use in a lexer class a have a class `Token` which represents a token of a specific type and its value, while the types are defined by the *enum* `TokenType` in which every token holds its own regular expression string, these again are stored in *static final String* variables.
Now my problem is that I naturally would create two seperate files, one for `Token` and one for `TokenType` and locate the regex strings in `TokenType`, where they belong.
Since this is not possible I currently have all three together in the `Token` class, but then all this is dragged along for every new `Token` object. And I can't really think of a reasonable "wrapper-class" to put around `TokenType` and its constants.

```
public class Token {

private static final String WHITESPACE_REGEX = "[\\s\\f\\r\\n]";
private static final String COMMA_REGEX = WHITESPACE_REGEX + "*," + WHITESPACE_REGEX + 
// ...

public enum TokenType {

    // can't be defined here...

    WHITESPACE(WHITESPACE_REGEX + "+"),
    COMMA(COMMA_REGEX),
    // ...

    // ... or here

    public final String pattern;

    private TokenType(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
}

private TokenType type;
private String value;

public Token(TokenType type, String value) {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
}

public TokenType getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: "Since this is not possible" - why not? "then all this is dragged along" - what do you precisely mean with "is dragged along"? "for every new Token object" - sounds you are not talking about a problem in file separation, but class separation. Sketch your code, that might clarify things.

Comment: At least in Java the enum constants need to be the first attributes inside the enum and if I put the regex strings at the end they are not defined yet for use in the enum constants.

Comment: I mean that if I create a new Token object, which of cause happens all the time, each of them has all the constants and the enum as attributes, which wouldn't be required.

Comment: "if I create a new Token object ... each of them has all the constants and the enum as attributes" - I think this is wrong, AFAIK Java enums are static. So they are created just *once*, no matter how many Token objects you create.

Comment: Well, you're right. But still this seems not to be nice to me.

Comment: An alternative would be to create a third helper class `TokenTypeRegexes` just for the purpose of holding the regex strings. That class might be package-private. Then you could also put those classes into three different files. But honestly, `Token` and `TokenType` seem to be so tightly coupled that it makes fully sense to me to let the current design as it is.